# Computing the joint density of $(X,Y,Z^2)$ if the joint density of $(X,Y,Z)$ is known

Tags: statistics

Think this is an elementary question, but haven't done any statistical theory for a while and I'm stuck on this. X, Y and Z are random variables. Assume Z has support on (0,∞).

Thank you.

Comment: I do not think you can say anything very conclusive if you do not know that $X,Y,Z$ are independent. That is because if they are dependent, and you do not know how, then $P(X\leq x,Y \leq y, Z^2 \leq z)$ may not have a discernible relation with $P(X \leq x, Y \leq  y, Z \leq z)$, since $Z^2 \leq z$ could possibly affect the values of $X$ and $Y$ in a manner we do not know. If $X,Y,Z$ are assumed independent, this is possible to do.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Y is independent of Z, but X is dependent on both Y and Z, so I guess there is no solution.

Comment: Yes, but would you like me to answer this question when they are independent?